# What is the equivalent of PHP Url rewriting (htaccess) in Angular 7?

Tags: node.js, angular7

I'm making an angular 7 and nodeJS website and I want to use htaccess to make URL rewriting . Is it possible? Is there an other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/origin_url', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/another_url');
});
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: I finally didn't need to do it but thank you anyway :)